# Grails embedded query array

Tags: mongodb, grails, embedded-database

i have a code like this on grails mongodb

```
//myDomain
class Plugin {
    List<String> projects = []
    //projects has name and description
}

//myController
def query = null
    if (params.q != null)
    {
        def q = '%'+ params.q +'%'
        query = Plugin.where {
            (projects.name =~ q || projects.name ==~ q)
        }
    }
//return null
```

why i can't find plugin by projects.name?

Comment: The `==~` condition is superfluous, you can remove it.

Comment: Need more code to answer. What/how do you return exactly? Also: maybe `params.q` is `null`?

Comment: Mongo only supports basic types List<String>, so you probably want to do List<Project> and a hasMany.

Comment: Also, if it is a list, shouldn't it be something like projects*.name?

Comment: "projects": {
     "0": {
       "description": "123",
       "name": "cms"
    },
     "1": {
       "description": "cms",
       "name": "codebucks"
    }
  } example i want to find when projects.name == 'cms', how i query in mongo? thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the property definition

```
List<String> projects = []
```

the elements of projects are Strings, that's why you can not query `projects.name`, which is not known to GORM.

And in your last comment, the value in a projects instance `"projects": { "0": { "description": "123", "name": "cms" }, "1": { "description": "cms", "name": "codebucks" } }` looks like a Map, where the project number is the key and a inner map containing name and description is the value, rather than a List.

To serve your purpose, you need to modify your domain class definition to ensure consistency between your model and data.

Comment: hi. thx for your answer, i finish it with createCriteria, i get projects.name, thx anyway.

Comment: So you made it with `List<String> projects = []`?  I wonder how did you do that. Could you please post your solution as an answer?

Comment: yes, i use List<String> projects, and my controller method def listPluginByProject()
 { 
  def objectInstanceList = []
  def q = '%'+ params.q +'%'
  
  def c = Plugin.createCriteria()
  def results = c.list {
         like('projects.name', q)
  }
  objectInstanceList = results }

Comment: i don't know why createCriteria still works without hibernate, i use grails 2.1.1, but maybe for safe i try with your suggest to modify domain class, or find another query.

Comment: Because mongodb gorm plugin provides similar functions.